# What makes Pulseaudio send network data when no stream?

Tags: pulseaudio

I have a pulseaudio over network installation that works well.

However as soon as Pulseaudio connects to a local network sink, it starts sending data, even if no streams are active. The data curve is exactly the same when one stream is active, it's like a phantom stream.

Pulseaudio 4 and all RTP modules disabled on both machine.

What could create such behavior ? I know it is possible to prevent it since I've done it in one of my numerous configuration attempts, but can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

I used PulseAudio Preferences to setup the network installation:

```
sudo apt-get install paprefs
```

When I deactivate and reactivate the two options in "Network access":

```
"Make discoverable PulseAudio network sound devices available locally"
"Make discoverable Apple AirTunes sound devices available locally"
```

the "phantom stream" is gone.